# Find intersection between geometries in two different datasets using R's sf package

Tags: r, intersection, r-sf

Using shapefiles downloaded from [this website](https://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/), I'm trying to obtain the (area of the) intersection of geometries, where each of these geometries is in a different file. However, the operation is throwing an error when I attempt it, and I have not been able to solve it.

The code below helps illustrate the problem that I'm having:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# Downloading files
temp <- tempfile()
URL <- "https://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/shp/districts097.zip"
download.file(URL, temp)
unzip(zipfile = temp)

temp <- tempfile()
URL <- "https://cdmaps.polisci.ucla.edu/shp/districts098.zip"
download.file(URL, temp)
unzip(zipfile = temp)

# Reading files
df0 <- st_read("districtShapes/districts097.shp") %>% 
  select(., STATENAME, DISTRICT) %>% 
  filter(., STATENAME == 'Alabama')
df1 <- st_read("districtShapes/districts098.shp") %>% 
  select(., STATENAME, DISTRICT) %>% 
  filter(., STATENAME == 'Alabama')

# Intersection operation
x <- st_intersection(df0[df0$DISTRICT == '1', 'geometry'], 
                     df1[df1$DISTRICT == '1', 'geometry']) %>%
  st_area(.) %>% as.numeric(.)
```

The intersection operation above does not work; it throws an error saying

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, attr(x, "sf_column"), value = list( : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 1
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: try calling `sf_use_s2(F)` first and see if it will allow you to calculate the area.

Answer (score 0):

If you fix the geometry of the polygons using `st_make_valid()` beforehand, it will work:

```r
df0 <- st_read("districtShapes/districts097.shp") %>%
  select(., STATENAME, DISTRICT) %>%
  filter(., STATENAME == 'Alabama') %>%
  st_make_valid(.)
df1 <- st_read("districtShapes/districts098.shp") %>%
  select(., STATENAME, DISTRICT) %>%
  filter(., STATENAME == 'Alabama') %>%
  st_make_valid(.)

x <- st_intersection(df0[df0$DISTRICT == '1', 'geometry'],
                     df1[df1$DISTRICT == '1', 'geometry']) %>%
  st_area(.) %>% as.numeric(.)
x #> 21063139796
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion and it did not work properly; in some cases, I still get the same error message as before. But the other suggestion that I received above worked in any case that I used it. Anyways, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @DOS, one more idea is to use `st_buffer(x, dist = 0, max_cells = 20000)` to fix data, if you want to still use calculations on the sphere. But that may not work in some cases either.